# Can somebody be happy?

Tags: gods, karma

Nobody in the world is absolutely happy. If a person does bad karma in previous life/this life, the person is punished. If this is not the case, god is happy with the person. But in many stories (like that of maharshi ved Vyas, when he makes god happy with his tapasya, god tells him that he will get a son as needed but he will have to give many pareeksha(tests)) , god takes tests of devotees. This gives rise to two questions:

1) Can't a person stay absolutely happy in life?

2) How to determine whether your suffering is due to god being unhappy with you, or whether you are giving pareeksha?

Comment: Yes, one can be completely happy. But such lucky persons are rare. Santosha (contentment) is the crucial thing here.

Comment: In this Kaliyuga and material world happiness is difficult to achieve since possesions and superficial contacts are admired. Both of which are temporary. By living according to an akarm lifestyle and reaching enlightment one can experience happiness. The happiness in the material world is always temporary. So 1) yes if certain conditions are met. 2) this is not possible to know.

Answer (score 1):

In reality, there is no eternal happiness nor eternal misery in this universe. What is happiness? Whenever some things happen according to your temporary personal selfish interest(called ego) like getting money, beautiful wife, respect from society, disease free life etc., a person in ignorance call it happiness, while misery is reverse of it that is living in poverty, diseases, old age and early death. So, its clear happiness for a person(in ego) starts with a healthy birth but ends in misery with diseased oldage death, same thing happens for an ignorant animal as well. So, all the material things like body and ego and its associated things like women and gold were never eternal in first place, so how can happiness born from them be eternal. Thats why, scriptures describe truth as "[**Sat Chida Ananda**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satcitananda)" [Par Brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Para_Brahman) Paramatma, a state of eternal bliss, but not temporary happiness.

> "Ekam Brahman, Dvitya Nasti"- Brahm Sutras
>
> "There is only one Brahman, and nothing else"
>
> [Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 4.4.22](http://www.advaita-philosophy.info/upanishads/Brihadaranyaka_Upanishad_Chapter_Four.html)   That great, **birthless Self
>   which is identified with the intellect** and is in the midst of the
>   organs, lies in the ether that is within the heart. It is the
>   controller of all, the lord of all, the ruler of all. It does not
>   become better through good work nor worse through bad work. It is the
>   lord of all, It is the ruler of all beings, It is the protector of all
>   beings. It is the bank that serves as the boundary to keep the
>   different worlds apart. The Brahmanas seek to know It through the
>   study of the Vedas, sacrifices, charity, and austerity consisting in a
>   dispassionate enjoyment of sense objects. **Knowing It alone one becomes
>   a sage/Rishi. Desiring this world (the Self) alone monks renounce their
>   homes.** This is (the reason for it): The ancient sages, it is said, did
>   not desire children (thinking), 'What shall we achieve through
>   children, we who have attained this Self, this world (result).' They,
>   it is said, renounced their desire for sons, for wealth and for the
>   worlds, and lived a mendicant life. That which is the desire for sons
>   is the desire for wealth, and that which is the desire for wealth is
>   the desire for the worlds, for both these are but desires. **This self
>   is That which has been described as 'Not this, not this.'** It is
>   imperceptible, for It is never perceived; undecaying, for It never
>   decays; unattached, for It is never attached; unfettered It never
>   feels pain, and never suffers injury. (It is but proper) that the sage
>   is never overtaken by these two thoughts, **'I did an evil act for
>   this,' and 'I did a good act for this.' He conquers both of them.
>   Things done or not done do not trouble him.**

Thats why these self-realized Swamis(lord of self) use the word Ananda in their names(like Swami Vivekananda, Yogananda, Dayananda, Shivananda etc.,) and renounce every material thing like family, wealth, wife, sons etc., because nothing is eternal and blissful except real self.

This is what Krishna explained in Bhagwat Geeta, while explaining the importance of [Nishkama Karma Yoga](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/3)(fruitless action) and maintaining contentment in all situations in life. Real eternal happiness comes from renunciation(of ego and material passions born from one's past animal instincts), listen and try to understand Neti Neti-[Nirvana Ashtakam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FZFvFWztOA)

> Bhagavad Gita 3.17 But those who rejoice in the self, who are
>   illumined and fully satisfied in the self, for them, there is no duty.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.18 Such self-realized souls have nothing to gain or
>   lose either in discharging or renouncing their duties. Nor do they
>   need to depend on other living beings to fulfill their self-interest.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.19 **Therefore, giving up attachment, perform actions as
>   a matter of duty, for by working without being attached to the fruits,
>   one attains the Supreme.**
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.20 – 3.21 By performing their prescribed duties, King
>   Janak and others attained perfection. You should also perform your
>   work to set an example for the good of the world. Whatever actions
>   great persons perform, common people follow. Whatever standards they
>   set, all the world pursues.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.22 **There is no duty for me to do in all the three
>   worlds, O Parth, nor do I have anything to gain or attain. Yet, I am
>   engaged in prescribed duties**.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.23 For if I did not carefully perform the prescribed
>   duties, O Parth, all men would follow my path in all respects.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.24 If I ceased to perform prescribed actions, all
>   these worlds would perish. I would be responsible for the pandemonium
>   that would prevail, and would thereby destroy the peace of the human
>   race.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.25 As ignorant people perform their duties with
>   attachment to the results, O scion of Bharat, so should the wise act
>   without attachment, for the sake of leading people on the right path.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.26 The wise should not create discord in the
>   intellects of ignorant people, who are attached to fruitive actions,
>   by inducing them to stop work. Rather, by performing their duties in
>   an enlightened manner, they should inspire the ignorant also to do
>   their prescribed duties.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.27 All activities are carried out by the three modes
>   of material nature. **But in ignorance, the soul, deluded by false
>   identification with the body, thinks itself to be the doer.**
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.28 **O mighty-armed Arjun, illumined persons distinguish
>   the soul as distinct from guṇas and karmas.** They perceive that it is
>   only the guṇas (in the shape of the senses, mind, etc.) that move
>   amongst the guṇas (in the shape of the objects of perception), and
>   thus they do not get entangled in them.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.29 **Those who are deluded by the operation of the guṇas
>   become attached to the results of their actions.** But the wise who
>   understand these truths should not unsettle such ignorant people who
>   know very little.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.30 Performing all works as an offering unto me,
>   constantly meditate on me as the Supreme. Become free from desire and
>   selfishness, and with your mental grief departed, fight!